# How to init default value of string_view with const char

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a method

```
void func(int bar, std::string_view sv = {})
```

But now I want to set the default value of sv using

```
const char def = 'X'
```

How do I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way:

```
const char def = 'X';
void func(int bar, std::string_view sv = {&def, 1});
```

Note that `std::string_view sv = {&def, 1}` produces a `std::string_view` to a string with no zero terminator, which may or may not be an issue.

If you need a zero-terminated `std::string_view`, then:

```
std::string_view const def_sv = "X";
void func(int bar, std::string_view sv = def_sv);
```

Or just:

```
void func(int bar, std::string_view sv = "X");
```

Comment: zero is not part of the view neither with `"X"`. (You cannot rely on validity of `*view.end()`).

Comment: @Jarod42 And that is a very rough edge of `std::string_view` which wants to be a common denominator for `char const*` and `std::string`.

Comment: Ah the & is what I missed. Totally forgot about the pointer to the start of the string thing and fiddled around for so long. Thank you. Also great that everyone reminds me of the weird edge condition here, appreciate that